# Get position of item in item in recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView with CardView items. In CardViews I have an imageView with same resource id in all items.

**I need to get position of clicked imageView in cardview (position of cardView).** For Cardviews I hasn't any problems to get an index of clicked CardView (for this I made custom listener). But I got stuck with imageView into cardView... [pic with recycler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfyw5.png).

How can I get the position? Is it possible? In my opinion, I can handle click of imageview in cardview listener (like recyclerview.setOnClickListener{ if (imageview.isClicked()...) }), but I think that it isn't best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably setting the `OnClickListener` of the recycler item in the `ViewHolder`. If so, just use the ViewHolder's `adapterItemPosition`.

If for some reading you're not inside the ViewHolder. Make a way to access the position. Something like the `tag`, or a custom `OnClickListener` implementation.